# Trying to get the results of a SOAP call using ksoap

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I have some code I wrote to test making a soup call. I get the result as follows

```
SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
```

When I tried to call a web service off my works server, I got an exception that in its description, said there was a type casting error in type casting to `SoapPrimitive`

I then change the code to, which worked.

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
```

Now I do not know how to get the result from the SoapObject. I tried this `result.toString()`, but that did not work.

Is there a way to get a SOAP call result from a `SoapObject` class?
Or should I do this another way?

Code

```
// EXCEPTION GOES OFF HERE!!!!!!
// SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
String Result = result.getProperty(0).toString();
SoapObject resultObj = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
```

How do I get the result from `resultObj`?

Comment: Based on my experience, using `getResponse()` then cast to `(SoapPrimitive)` or `(SoapObject)` is the correct way. Have you inspected the XML returned by `SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse()`? If it's permitted, post the `result.toString()` on the question.

Comment: Try replacing `SoapObject` by only `Object`, then you should get the result when you say `response.toString()`. May I know what is `soapEnvelope` ? Is it an object of `SoapSerializationEnvelope`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 Object result = soapEnvelope.getResponse();
```

instead of

```
 SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
```